# ORDER placement for trigger in t-sql

Tags: t-sql, trigger, sap-sql-anywhere-16

I'm using Sybase ASE version 16.0.0.1915, (follows t-sql syntax) and trying to create a new trigger. This new trigger emulates another existing trigger, however is slightly modified. It would be a whole lot harder to modify the existing trigger to address both "workflows", so copying into a new trigger with modified details and an order of "2" would be my preferred solution.

I'm reading in the docs, that in order to create a new trigger based on the same action, I need to set the order for the triggers to fire off. If no order is specified, it is assigned order of 0 (first).
[Docs](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1600/doc/html/ate1372183515788.html)

So here is my trigger, the existing similar trigger does not have an order set. When I place "ORDER 2" into the create statement (after the name, before "on" in row 1), I keep getting syntax error -131.

I've also tried placing the "ORDER 2" after the table name, before "for", and after "insert", before "as". All producing the same error -131.

So what am I doing wrong? Is there some other problem with this trigger preventing me to use the ORDER clause?

```
create trigger "DBA"."WKM_autoFillCL143" on
"DBA"."case_checklist" for insert
as
if((select top 1 "inserted"."code" from "inserted") in( '143' ) )
  begin
    declare @parentRef integer,@desc varchar(255),@desc1 varchar(255),@checkID integer
    set @parentRef = (select top 1 "parent_ref" from "inserted")
    if(@parentRef <> '0')
      begin
        set @desc = (select "description" from "case_checklist" where "checklist_id" = @parentRef)
        if(@desc is not null)
          begin
            set @checkID = (select top 1 "checklist_id" from "inserted")
            update "WKM_RecordChecklistMapping" set "c143" = @checkID where "c142" = @parentRef
            declare @tabid integer
            set @tabid = (select top 1 "tab_id" from "WKM_recordChecklistMapping" where "c142" = @parentRef)
            set @tabid = (select top 1 "tab_id" from "user_tab2_data" where "tab_id" = @tabid)
            if(@tabid is not null)
              begin
                declare @recProvider varchar(255),@recsRequested varchar(255),@dateFrom "datetime",@dateTo "datetime"
                set @recProvider = (select top 1 "Provider_Name" from "user_tab2_data" where "tab_id" = @tabid)
                set @recsRequested = (select top 1 "Records_Requested" from "user_tab2_data" where "tab_id" = @tabid)
                set @dateFrom = (select top 1 "For_Dates_From" from "user_tab2_data" where "tab_id" = @tabid)
                set @dateTo = (select top 1 "Through" from "user_tab2_data" where "tab_id" = @tabid)
                set @desc1 = 'Receipt '+@recProvider+' Records? '+@recsRequested+', dates '+"coalesce"(convert(varchar(255),@dateFrom,1),'00/00/00')+' to '+"coalesce"(convert(varchar(255),@dateTo,1),'00/00/00')
                set @checkID = (select top 1 "checklist_id" from "inserted")
                update "case_checklist" set "description" = @desc1,"staff_assigned" = 'ZKS',"due_date" = ("today"()+7) where "checklist_id" = @checkID
              end
          end
      end
  end
```

Comment: @BrentOzar says: [**The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers**](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) you don't take into account multiple rows in `inserted`

Comment: SAP SQLAnywhere 16 v16.0.0.1915, from what I gather @markp-fuso

Comment: Which correlates to these docs, showing ORDER coming before "on" (where I originally placed it), which still doesn't work. Oy vey. 
http://dcx.sap.com/sa160/en/dbreference/create-trigger-statement.html

Comment: there are a lot of differences in the `create trigger` syntax between `ASE` and `SQLAnywhere` ... net result being your current (`ASE`) `create trigger` command has quite a few syntax issues (as far as `SQLAnywhere` is concerned); I've consolidated my comments (+ fix for current syntax issue) into an answer; if you still have problems with the syntax I'd suggest starting a new question ... tagged for `sybase-sql-anywhere` ... and including your `SQLAnywhere`-specific `create trigger` command; this Q&A would need a complete rewrite and is probably not worth the effort ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4x different RDBMS products under the `Sybase` name ... `Adaptiver Server Enterprise (ASE)`, `SQLAnywhere`, `IQ` and `Advantage`.  The 4x products do **not** share a common SQL language/syntax.

The question references a link for the `create trigger` syntax in `ASE`.

The sample code in the question appears to also be for `ASE`.

However, from the comments we've discovered the OP is actually using the `SQLAnywhere` product (version `16.0.0.1915`).  And while `SQLAnywhere` does provide some half-workable support for `ASE's` `T-SQL` dialect, it does not include a common syntax for the `create trigger` command.

From the comments: OP has located the documentation for `SQLAnyhere's` [create trigger](http://dcx.sap.com/sa160/en/dbreference/create-trigger-statement.html) command.

Using one of the examples from that link (scroll down to find `CREATE TRIGGER myTrig`), and modifying OP's current trigger code to match the documentation, I'm thinking OP's looking for something like:

```
create trigger "DBA"."WKM_autoFillCL143"
after insert order 4 on "DBA"."case_checklist"
REFERENCING NEW AS inserted
FOR EACH STATEMENT
BEGIN
....
```

**NOTES**:

- I work primarily on `ASE`, and my `SQLAnywhere` experience is rather limited, so OP may need to tweak the above to work correctly in `SQLAnywhere`; also ...
- OP should review the various options available via `SQLAnywhere's` `create trigger` command (eg, should the trigger fire before or after the insert?)
- OP will need to review the rest of the current (`ASE/T-SQL`) trigger code to see which parts can be used 'as is' in `SQLAnywhere` and which parts will need to be rewritten to match `SQLAnywhere's` syntax
- OP will also want to verify `SQLAnywhere's` support for quoted identifiers (ie, does the current use of double-quoted identifiers meet `SQLAnywhere's` syntax?)

Answer (score 0):

@mustaccio has already answered your question in the comments: place it just before `AS` at the top of the trigger.

You have a **much bigger** problem though. Your trigger does not deal with multi-row inserts. It needs a full rewrite. I hope I've got these joins right, as I don't have your full relational model:

```
create trigger "DBA"."WKM_autoFillCL143" on
"DBA"."case_checklist" for insert
as

if(not exists(select 1
    from inserted i
    inner join case_checklist c where c.checklist_id = i.parent_ref
    where i.code = '143' and i.parent_ref <> '0' and c.description is not null))
  return

update w
set c143 = i.checklist_id
from inserted i
join WKM_RecordChecklistMapping w on w.c142 = i.parent_ref 
where i.code = '143' and i.parent_ref <> '0' and c.description is not null

update c
set description =
        'Receipt ' + ut.Provider_Name + ' Records? ' + ut.Records_Requested +
        ', dates ' + coalesce(convert(varchar(255), ut.For_Dates_From, 1), '00/00/00') +
        ' to ' + coalesce(convert(varchar(255), ut.Through, 1), '00/00/00'),
    staff_assigned = 'ZKS',
    due_date = (today()+7)
from inserted i
inner join WKM_RecordChecklistMapping w on w.c142 = i.parent_ref 
inner join user_tab2_data ut on ut.tab_id = w.tab_id
inner join case_checklist c on c.checklist_id = i.checklist_id
where i.code = '143' and i.parent_ref <> '0' and c.description is not null
```

Is `parent_ref <> '0'` correct? It looks like you actually wanted to write `parent_ref is not null`. Either way, I hope this is not an int column that you are comparing to text.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The trigger above is not new, it's been in place in production for years now and "working" fine. Management wanted another "workflow" automated, so I copied the existing trigger, changed a few parameters (c140 becomes c142) and now I just need to get it to fire after the original trigger, but still having trouble with that.

Comment: I'm running version 16.0.0.1915, which apparently should support multiple triggers, but I continue to get error -131 wherever I place the "order" clause. I've attempted putting it after "insert"/before "as", after "on"/before {table_name}, and after {trigger_name}/before "on". Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: To answer your last question, "parent_ref <> '0'" should be correct. I believe the default value is 0 of type int. So were just checking to see that "parent_ref" has some value other than 0.

Comment: @boog Depends if it's nullable, then the default is `null`. The fact it worked for years just means either no-one noticed, or only 1 row inserts were done. That code **definitely** does not work with multi-row inserts

Comment: it doesn't do multi-row inserts